# ssh doesn't auto start up in ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I installed ssh using 
apt-get install ssh

it showed that it was successfully installed
but ssh cannot start up with the booting of ubuntu,
every time i need to log in ubuntu and start the service by hand.

i searched the web and came to a method of using update-rc.d ssh defaults 99

but it also fails.

is there anything else should be configured?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick..

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

EDIT: If your network is configured with Network Manager then the connection will not be established until a user logs in through the GUI. For manually configuring you have to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file, have a look at this guide and if you use wireless you can have a look here

Origianl Post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3913/start-ssh-server-on-boot

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can try.

Check the status of SSH -- are they errors?

```
$ sudo /sbin/service sshd status
```

Also, it might be a problem that you invoke update-rc.d on "ssh".  You might try it on "sshd", which is the deamon that manages instances of "ssh".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Bitnami stack, by default the ssh.conf file not present in /etc/init/

In this case:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf.back /etc/init/ssh.conf
sudo start ssh
```

That should solve the problem.

source: https://wiki.bitnami.com/@api/deki/pages/97/pdf